# Let $f$ be a function defined by $f(x)= $\begin{cases} (x-r)^2&r-1\le x <r+1 \\ 1 & r+1\le x <r+2 \end{cases}$, where....

Tags: integration

> Let $f$ be a function defined by $f(x)= \begin{cases} (x-r)^2&r-1\le x <r+1 \\ 1 & r+1\le x <r+2 \end{cases}$, where $r=3k, k\in I$. Find $\int_0^{90} f(x).dx$

Here is how I am defining the function

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} x^2& -1\le x <1 \\ 1 & 1\le x \le 2 \\ (x-3)^2 & 2\le x\le 4 \\1& 4\le x \le 5 \\ .....\\.... \end {cases}$$

Now that the function is defined, I do not know how to use it in the integral. It has something to do with the periodicity of the function but I don’t know what the period is.

Comment: Hint: note that $$\int_{-1}^1 x^2=\int_2^4 {(x-3)}^2=\int_5^7 {(x-6)}^2=..$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

1. Break up the integral: $$I=\int_0^{90}f(x)dx= \int_0^1\phi_0(x)dx+\int_1^2g(x)dx+\int_2^4\phi_1(x)dx+\cdots+\int_{86}^{88}\phi_{29}(x)dx+\int_{88}^{89}g(x)dx+\int_{89}^{90}\phi_{30}(x)dx$$

where $g(x)=1$ and $\phi_{k}(x)=(x-3k)^2$ for $k \in \{0,\cdots,30\}$

2. Use periodicity:

$$\int_{-1}^1 x^2dx= \int_{-1+3k}^{1+3k} (x-3k)^2dx =\cfrac{2}{3} $$

3. Condense 1. using sigma notation:

$$I=\sum_{k=0}^{29}\int_{1+3k}^{3k+2} g(x)dx + \sum_{k=1}^{29}\int_{-1+3k}^{3k+1} \phi_{k}(x)dx +\int_0^1\phi_0(x)dx+\int_{89}^{90}\phi_{30}(x)dx$$

Evaluate the integrals and then the summations.

> Answer: $I=50$

Edit: I believe I owe an explanation to hint 2. You can justify it by using "transformations", just like in pre-calculus.

If $f(x)=x^2$ for $x\in[-1,1]$, then we can "shift" the graph from the interval $[-1,1]$ to $[2,4]$ by introducing the translation $g(x)=f(x-3)$, which translates $f(x)$ three units to the right.

Or, if you prefer, use a u-substitution:

Let $x=u-3$ (and $dx=du$) so then:

$$\int_{-1}^1 x^2dx= \int_{-1+3}^{1+3} (u-3)^2du =\int_{2}^{4} (u-3)^2du  $$

Comment: If you converting $x\to x-3k$, shoudnt the limits also change similarity ie.$-1\to -1-3k$?

Comment: See my explanation above. If you still need further clarification, let me know.

Comment: Why didn’t you include $\phi_0$ and $\phi_{30}$ under the sigma function for $\phi_k$. Why write it separately?

Comment: @Aditya Because the integral for these functions is only $\frac{1}{2}$ the integral for one of the $\phi_k$'s. However, note that sum of the integrals for $\phi_0$ and $\phi_{30}$ must equal $\frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help!! Really appreciate it